# How to make multiple lines after System.out.println in the cmd?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChristmasSong{
    public static void main (String[] args)

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What would like to do? (Do one action) (Do another action) Exit");
```

This is the beginning of my program. Using Java, how do I make the expression inside the System.out.println appear in mulitple lines on the cmd when I execute the program?

Like I want to make it say

```
What would you like me to do?
(Do one action)
(do another action)
exit
```

instead of

```
What would you like me to do? (Do one action) (Do another action) Exit
```

and I want the user to type in their option and make the program act according to the option. This is more of format and style kind of question. It probably sounds stupid, but I'm a beginner. Just a week of experience in class and I want to get better. If you could help me out. That would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to write System.out.println() mulitple times? Or are you asking how to get user input?

Comment: Either separate it with with different `System.out.println` or add a \n between the strings like `System.out.println("What would like to do?\n(Do one action) ...... ")`

Comment: I don't think you should use "\n" in a println command. The 'ln' stands for line. There are other more suitable methods to print formatted Strings.

Comment: Ok, \n for a new line. Gotcha. What is another way of formatting strings. I am trying to have it display an entire song. (Got a weird project). I want to make the lyrics in verse form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**System.out.println()** outputs line breaks using the platform's preferred line separator

**\n** The newline (line feed) character ('\u000A')

```
    System.out.println("What would you like me to do?");
    System.out.println("(Do one action)");
    System.out.println("(do another action)")
    System.out.println("exit");
```

alternatively

```
System.out.println("What would you like me to do?\n(Do one action)\n(do another action)\nexit");
```

The second version outputs newline characters, which is likely to be inappropriate on Windows or Mac OS.

For more info regarding performance have a look [System.out.println() vs \n in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685665/system-out-println-vs-n-in-java)

Comment: Ok I got it better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In *Java 15*, a new feature called **Text Blocks** are available while in *Java 13* and *Java 14*, these are preview features. 
 
Text blocks help to achieve the results more elegantly and are readable than the accepted answer.

Text blocks starts with three double-quote marks `"""`
Inside the text blocks, we can freely use newlines and quotes without the need for escaping line breaks.

Example:

```
String text = """
        Players take turns marking a square. 
        Only squares not already marked can be picked. 
        Once a player has marked three squares in a row, he or she wins! 
        If all squares are marked and no three squares are the same, a tied game is declared. 
        Have Fun!""");
```