# Trouble looping code when the input is invalid

Tags: java, loops, do-while

```
do {
            loop = false;
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Score")){
                System.out.println("You have chose to input a score.\nEnter your score here: ");
                score = kbInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("What was the best possible score?");
                total = kbInput.nextDouble();
                finalScore = score / total * 100;
                percent = (finalScore + "%");
                if (finalScore >= 90){
                    grade = 'A';
                } else if (finalScore >= 80){
                    grade = 'B';
                } else if (finalScore >= 70){
                    grade = 'C';
                } else if (finalScore >= 60){
                    grade = 'D';
                } else {
                    grade = 'F';
                }
                System.out.println("You got " + percent + ". Which is a letter grade '" + grade + "'.");
                loop = false;
            } else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Percent")) {
                System.out.println("You have chosen to input a percent.\nEnter your percent here: ");
                finalScore = kbInput.nextDouble();
                if (finalScore >= 90){
                    grade = 'A';
                } else if (finalScore >= 80){
                    grade = 'B';
                } else if (finalScore >= 70){
                    grade = 'C';
                } else if (finalScore >= 60){
                    grade = 'D';
                } else {
                    grade = 'F';
                }
                System.out.println("You got a letter grade '" + grade + "'.");
                loop = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, I don't understand that.");
                loop = true;
            }
        } while (loop = true);
```

I am fairly new to Java and I have been taking a class and doing mini projects on my own. My plan was to have the code loop back to the beginning whenever you reached the final if statement due to entering an invalid string (i.e. anything besides Score and Percent). I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, it only loop sections of the if / else statements.

Comment: Then you need to populate `userInput` inside your loop.

Comment: `==` for comparison, `=` for assignment... also don't compare booleans using `==`.

Answer (score 4):

You have made a classic mistake that Java newbies make.  You intended to use `==`, but accidentally miss-typed it as `=`.  You could fix the typo, but there is a BETTER solution that will avoid this problem in the future.

You should not use `==` to test booleans.  Instead, you should rewrite your code as per the following pattern:

```
while (loop = true) {     // BUG!!!    

while (loop == true) {    // WRONG

while (loop) {            // CORRECT

while (loop = false) {    // BUG!!

while (loop == false) {   // WRONG

while (!loop) {           // CORRECT
```

This advice applies to pretty much every use of `==` with boolean operands.  (The exception is `op1 == op2` where **neither** `op1` or `op2` are *boolean literals*.)

**UPDATE**

There are also problems with the way you get input from the user.

1. You are not reading `userInput` within the loop.  That might be a problem, depending on the requirements, and on whether / how it was initialized prior to the start of the loop.
2. If the user enters a bad floating point number, you will get an exception.  This includes the case where the user enters something like "100.0 points".
3. You don't validate the inputs; e.g. test for negative scores, scores greater than the maximum, percentages outside of the range 0..100.

Finally, the way you are terminating the loop is clunky.  It would be better to do something like this:

```
while (true) {
    // do stuff
    if (...) {
        // we want to terminate the loop
        break;   // <<------
    }
    // do more stuff
}
```

Comment: This only deals with one of the two causes of the problem. It won't fix the program.  Stephen, your answers are usually much better than this.

Comment: Don't you mean 4?  Your comments are usually better than this.  Besides, it is NOT for us to fix code in homework questions.  That is for the student to do.

Comment: Well, you've fixed it now, with your update.  This is now a really good answer.

Comment: This isn't a question for homework, it is just me messing around to try and get a better grasp of other concepts that I know / want to know. As for the code, I read and re-read your comments and edits, but I still can't seem to get the code to loop back to the beginning, rather than just repeat "Sorry, I don't understand that."

Comment: OK ... I have broken my personal rule against doing this, and written you a sample solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are still struggling to understand, here is a "sample solution" to the programming problem:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbdInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String mode = "";
        double percent = -1;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter 'score' or 'percent': ");
            mode = kbdInput.next().toLowerCase();
            kbdInput.nextLine();
            if (mode.equals("score") || mode.equals("percent")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("I don't understand that.  Try again.");
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (mode.equals("score")){
                    System.out.println("You chose to input a score.");
                    System.out.println("Enter it here: ");
                    double score = kbdInput.nextDouble();
                    kbdInput.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("What is the best score?");
                    double total = kbdInput.nextDouble();
                    kbdInput.nextLine();
                    percent = score / total * 100;
                    if (score >= 0.0 && total > 0.0 &&
                        percent >= 0.0 && percent <= 100.0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("The score / best score you " +
                       "gave make no sense.");
                } else if (mode.equals("percent")) {
                    System.out.println("You chose to input a percent.");
                    System.out.println("Enter it here: ");
                    percent = kbdInput.nextDouble();
                    kbdInput.nextLine();
                    if (percent >= 0.0 && percent <= 100.0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("The percent you gave is not " +
                       "between 0 and 100.");
                }
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                kbdInput.nextLine();
                System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
            }
            System.out.println("Try again.");
        }
        if (percent >= 0.0 && percent <= 100.0) {
            char grade;
            if (percent >= 90){
                grade = 'A';
            } else if (percent >= 80){
                grade = 'B';
            } else if (percent >= 70){
                grade = 'C';
            } else if (percent >= 60){
                grade = 'D';
            } else {
                grade = 'F';
            }
            System.out.println("You got " + percent +
                   "%. Which is a letter grade '" + grade + "'.");
        }
    }
}
```

The things to note:

1. I have split this into two loops.  One to request and validate the "mode" of inputting the scores.  And the second to actually input them.  (I have inferred this was a requirement from your code.  That may not be correct.)
2. There is a lot more validation of the inputs than in your version.
3. I have used `kbdInput.nextLine()` to "consume" unwanted input in a few places.  Note that the `next` methods leave any input characters that they don't want or can't recognize in the input buffer.  If you are not careful, the next call to `nextXxxx` will attempt to parse the same characters all over again.
4. I explicitly catch and deal with errors in entering numbers; see the exception handler.
5. I have moved common code to calculate and display the grade to the end.
6. I have changed your multi-line println statements into separate statements.  There is a good reason for this.

   - `"\n"` is not always the **correct** way to output a line break.  It depends on the execution platform
   - `println` will do it correctly, assuming that the output is destined for the same machine that the code is running on.
   - See also: [System.out.println() vs \n in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685665/system-out-println-vs-n-in-java/6685928#6685928)

Finally, this code will NOT deal with the case where the user enters an END-OF-FILE at the keyboard (e.g. ^D on Linux).

Exercise: See what happens if you do that.  Work out what happens, and find an appropriate fix for it.